# Set the actual DOCUMENT_ROOT for Apache with PHP

Tags: php, document-root

I'm trying to have several versions of the same PHP application in different directories. The application is written so that it has to be in Apache's Document_root.

I have tried `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/htdocs/version2';` but that only works for things being included using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'filename.php'`.

All other files executed is in the original root /htdocs/version1.

How can I make the document_root to actually change for a PHP session and not just setting the variable `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: I don't think this can actually be possible, you would then be able to take over someone else's website on a shared hosting environment. What you could do however, is use mod_rewrite to rewrite all files, including images files etc. It may be much easier however to simply set up multiple vhosts pointing to the same folder.

Comment: Rewriting all the .htaccess file! huh! Buddy Just Replace The htdocs/ string using regex whenever you store $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in a variable!

Comment: Could they be different [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)?

Comment: How can that even be possible. If you change your document root then how can even your script execute from where it is at. I don't think that is possible

Comment: Hi Guys! Thanks for all your thoughts. Well, perhaps it is not possible. The idea was to have a database store what version a particular users is using to match the database version and the code version. The versions are pretty similar but version two has some new functionality of course. What I mean is that the first include I make is the same in all versions but from there they are a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything what you're just doing (what you wrote just now at least, like server stuff).

**Situation 1.**

If you want to use 2 folders as a separate websites (on a local machine), just copy those 2 folders in a htdocs folders and youre done. Use

`http://localhost/vesion1` //version 1 is actually your copied folder name.. and version2 also

```
http://localhost/vesion2
```

entries to access them.

ps:if this aint gonna work, you should edit your website configuration .php file and change main url / path to version1 /or version 2 ie! (That is your problem actually, not "server root".)

If you have database driven url set, you should create new DB for your copy/pasted website (or force new main url/path manually).

For ie.. you can have 10 "versions" with only one DB, or 10 versions with 10 DBs (databases).

**Situation 2.**

If you want to run 2 versions/sites using one index.php (root index) - what are not 2 versions actually, but more like a "2 websites in one" - you should edit .htaccess file to jump over root index / or not.

I'm kinda confused what youre trying to achieve but I guess situation 1 is a go (if you're trying to do this on a local machine).

Comment: Thanks you very much for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately do I not think any of the suggestions will better the situation. I want the url to be same but send the session to one of the versions depending on weather that user has updated to latest version or not. Transparently.

Comment: Then it wont better the situation. Sounds like a complex for one index.php and lots of folders (option 2). But its impossible to explain this way.